# SoundCloud API - can I filter my tracks by tags and/or genre?

Tags: php, filtering, soundcloud

I am having trouble finding any info on returning my tracks with a particular tag and/or genre.

For instance, this doesn't seem to work:

`http://api.soundcloud.com/users/123/tracks.xml?genre=drums&client_id=[myClientID]`

Basically, I want to retrieve all my tracks then filter them by genre or keyword.
Is there a way to do this either with GET or with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all of your tracks, and then filter them afterwards.